# Why doesn't iTunes show the contents of a particular youtube rss feed? 

Tags: itunes, rss, youtube

Does anybody have any idea why iTunes does not show the contents of this rss feed?

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/bionicturtledotcom/uploads?v=2

RSS clients like Google Reader and others process it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the RSS feed doesn't include the "enclosure" tag, which iTunes uses to list the audio or video file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see this RSS feed is only linking to a html page and not to actual media files. Even if it did it would probably some weird video format that iTunes isn't capable of playing.

Youtube just doesn't have a good RSS feed implementation. Unrelated your youtuber-subscripion: Everyone who is calling his youtube channel a *podcast* is just wrong